# Why do I need a type variable in Haskell's data/newtype?

Tags: haskell

It appears that data/newtype type constructors always need a type variable.

Suppose I have just some nesting of tuples and lists, and I want to hide the implementation and restrict the client to use a certain set of functions only?  How would I decide which element is of "variable" type and which is not?

**Edit**: Before anybody gets confused: **you don't need a type variable!**.

I asked this question because many examples include a type variable, but data/newtype work perfectly without one:

```
data Foo = Foo Int deriving Show
x = Foo 42
```

Comment: You should at least try it, shouldn't you? Because, it may not be so how it appears to you.

Comment: Please add an example of what you're talking about. `data` or `newtype` constructors certainly do _not_ need any type variables, consider e.g. `newtype StupidInt = Stupid Int`.

Comment: Monomorphic data types (e.g. Bool) are possible, and you can abstract the constructors away (you'll see if...then...else more often than case...on with Bools, and you have loads of combinators, like not and &&).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and sorry for blindfold question.

Answer (score 3):

```
data T

data T = T

data T = T | S

data T = T (T, T)
```

'nuf said.

Comment: data T = (T, T) is not Haskell

Comment: T T, T | T (T T) T T T